# JQuery not using first found item in selector

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure how why JQuery is not using the first item in my selector.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo1" value="Hello World">
```

This is what I expect should work, but returns "undefinied"

```
$("#foo1").checked
```

Strangely, this works correctly...

```
$("#foo1")[0].checked
```

Am I missing something? I'm using JQuery 1.9.1 and Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery function `$( selector )` does not return an element but a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) which is *kind of* like an array. One thing it does **not have** is a `checked` property.

If you want to get the `checked` property without resorting to referencing an element by index (as in your second example), you can use

```
$('#foo1').prop('checked')
```

See http://api.jquery.com/prop/

> Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements